# spring-kafka (not integration) consumer not consuming message

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am integrating my application with spring-kafka (not spring-integration-kafka). Here is spring documentation for project : http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle

My producer works perfectly but consumer is not consuming any messages. Any pointers.

Here is my configuration:

```
@EnableKafka
public class MyConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.broker.list}") // List of servers server:port,
    private String kafkaBrokerList;

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, Message>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, Message> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(12);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(60000L);
        factory.setAutoStartup(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, Message> consumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer<Message> messageJsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Message.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new IntegerDeserializer(), messageJsonDeserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBrokerList);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
        return props;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(@Payload Message message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

** Edited with more information **

Thanks Gary for response. I don't see any exceptions in log. Also I tried `KafkaTemplate` with similar configuration and i am able to publish message to queue but for consumer, no luck. I am changing code to use String instead of my Message object. Here are parts of log:

```
2016-07-11 09:31:43.314 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] o.a.k.c.c.ConsumerConfig [AbstractConfig.java:165] ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []  
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000  
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer  
    group.id = 
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]  
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50  
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8  
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576  
    bootstrap.servers = [app1.qa:9092, app1.qa:9093, app2.qa:9092, app2.qa:9093, app3.qa:9092, app3.qa:9093]  
    retry.backoff.ms = 10000  
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit  
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null  
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05  
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS  
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX  
    enable.auto.commit = true  
    ssl.key.password = null  
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500  
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000  
    connections.max.idle.ms = 60000  
    ssl.truststore.password = null  
    session.timeout.ms = 15000  
    metrics.num.samples = 2  
    client.id =   
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null  
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer  
    ssl.protocol = TLS  
    check.crcs = true  
    request.timeout.ms = 40000  
    ssl.provider = null  
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]  
    ssl.keystore.location = null  
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000  
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 10000  
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768  
    ssl.cipher.suites = null  
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS  
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT  
    ssl.truststore.location = null  
    ssl.keystore.password = null  
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509  
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000  
    fetch.min.bytes = 1  
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072  
    auto.offset.reset = latest
```

Also I do see following in log:

```
2016-07-11 09:31:53.515 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-consumer-10] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:224] partitions revoked:[]  
2016-07-11 09:31:53.515 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-consumer-11] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:224] partitions revoked:[]  
2016-07-11 09:31:53.516 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-consumer-3] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:224] partitions revoked:[]  
2016-07-11 09:31:53.516 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-consumer-12] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:224] partitions revoked:[]  
2016-07-11 09:31:53.578 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-consumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:529] Marking the coordinator 2147483639 dead.  
2016-07-11 09:31:53.578 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-consumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:529] Marking the coordinator 2147483639 dead.  
2016-07-11 09:31:53.578 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-consumer-10] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:529] Marking the coordinator 2147483639 dead.  
2016-07-11 09:31:53.578 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-consumer-12] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:529] Marking the coordinator 2147483639 dead.
```

Comment: Your code looks good. So, not sure which sample you are looking for. Even if we add one, it will be pretty simple and without so wide configuration options. So, or you connect to wrong Kafka and/or topic or there is something in logs indicating an error somehow.

Comment: Thanks Gary for response. I don't see any exceptions in log. Also I tried KafkaTemplate with similar configuration and i am able to publish message to queue but for consumer, no luck. I am changing code to use String instead of my Message object. Due to comments length limitation, i have added this in main post.

Comment: You can track more info in the logs after adding this category: `org.apache.kafka.clients=DEBUG`

Comment: If you are familiar with `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/kafka` you can modify it locally and change `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` to the desired `@KafkaListener` with the same logic.

Comment: i´m facing a similar problem.. using kafka and zookeper .. i cant send messages to my remote server.. it only works if i have all things locally

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380903/i-cant-conect-to-kafka-from-external-machine

Answer (score 2):

The referenced above documentation says:

> Although Serializer/Deserializer API is pretty simple and flexible from the low-level Kafka Consumer and Producer perspective, it is not enough on the Messaging level, where KafkaTemplate and @KafkaListener are present. To easy convert to/from org.springframework.messaging.Message, Spring for Apache Kafka provides MessageConverter abstraction with the MessagingMessageConverter implementation and its StringJsonMessageConverter customization.

But in your case you combine `MessageConverter`:

```
        factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
```

with custom `Deserializer`:

```
        JsonDeserializer<Message> messageJsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Message.class);
```

Simplest fix for you case should be using `StringDeserializer` instead:

https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer.html

Talking about the above given log messages `Marking the coordinator XXX dead.`, the error is not related to `spring-kafka` project, but means that problem is with your Kafka configuration. In my case we had such kind of issues when Kafka nodes where unreachable for zookeper. For troubleshooting the issue I recommend you to install both Kafka & Zookeper locally and make sure that producing-consuming works on it, using `kafka-console-producer` and `kafka-console-consumer`, e.g.:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_command_line.html

Then, as the next stage, you may check your sample `spring-kafka` application with the same local installation.

Comment: At the same time, `JsonDeserializer` allows using POJO for payload, extracting it's instances from Kafka's messages.

Comment: Thanks Stepio, I tried with removing StringJsonMessageConverter, but still i don't see messages are consumed. Also to reduce complexity, I am changing code to test with StringDesilizer instead of custom JSON deserilizer.  `code`  
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new IntegerDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());  `code`
  
and consumer is changed to:  
`code`    containerProps.setMessageListener((MessageListener<Integer, String>) message -> {  
        System.out.println(message.value());  
    });`code`